# В функцию получаю переменную со значением ('+' или '*') Javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер!

как выполнить арифметическую операцию, если все операнды поступают через переменные.

```
function summ(f,s, operator){
    return result (f operator s)
}
summ(1,2,'+')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function summ(f, s, operator){ 
  switch(operator) {
  case '+':
    return f + s;
  case '*':
    return f * s;
  case '-':
    return f - s;
  case '/':
    return f / s;
  }
} 

console.log(summ(1,2,'+'));
console.log(summ(3,2,'*'));
console.log(summ(1,2,'?'));
console.log(summ(25,5,'/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval(f + operator + s)` нужно делать через eval )) проще и работает )

Comment: "Проще" - это замечательно :). Спасибо, что научили.

Comment: а почему в кавычках? :D

Comment: Так как это цитата.